# How to organize solution for multi-framework WCF service

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wcf

I'm wondering what is the best way to organize files for WCF service. The service should be compiled for two versions of .NET Framework 3.5 and 4.5 (behind of scene it works with different versions of third-party provisioning).

The first thought is to create the files structure like this:

```
WcfProject
  |-File1.cs
  |-File2.cs
  |-MyWcfService.Net35.csproj
  |-MyWcfService.Net45.csproj
  |-??? Web.config ???
|-MySolution.Net35.sln
|-MySolution.Net45.sln
```

Project files are configured for different framework versions. But I have no idea what to do with Web.config files, which should be different for 3.5 and 4.5.

Another way I see is to create different project folders (for 3.5 and 4.5) containing code files. In this case the common files are added to the project as links:

```
WcfProject.Net35
  |-File1.cs
  |-File2.cs
  |-MyWcfService.csproj
  |-Web.config
WcfProject.Net45
  |-File1.cs (link to ..\WcfProject.Net35\File1.cs)
  |-File2.cs (link to ..\WcfProject.Net35\File2.cs)
  |-MyWcfService.csproj
  |-Web.config
|-MySolution.Net35.sln
|-MySolution.Net45.sln
```

What do you think guys? There is another way to solve my problem or the second solution is already the best what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

I would do this:

1. Create a private [NuGet server](http://nugetserver.net/).
2. For each common dependency, create a build which packages and publishes the assembly to NuGet.
3. Grab the required dependencies into your **completely separate** 3.5 and 4.5 solutions.
4. Deploy and manage them as separate concerns.

Or, skip steps one and two and just manage the dependencies in source control.

> Can these solutions share some C# files?

Yes if you use NuGet you can specify static content to be packaged which will then be automatically added when you grab the package. Look at [this](https://docs.nuget.org/create/creating-and-publishing-a-package), which tells you how to use the `<files/>` node.

If you're not going to use nuget, you can also still files as links into visual studio from some common location. Use the Add as link... on the Add Existing Item dialog:

[image]

This will mean that the file will be included as source during compilation, but can be held outside the actual solution folders.

Comment: Tom, thank you! One more question.
    Grab the required dependencies into your completely separate 3.5 and 4.5 solutions.
Can these solutions share some C# files? For instance, some class-helper which can be compiled as 3.5 or 4.5 without modifications.